# How to navigate from a nested BottomTabNavigator to the parent StackNavigator in React-Navigation v5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I've a problem with a `BottomTabNavigator` nested in a `StackNavigator` in React-Native using React-Navigation v5

This is my `StackNavigator`

```js
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="AircraftList" component={AircraftList} />
      <Stack.Screen name="MainTabNavigator" component={MainTabNavigator} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

In the `AircraftList` the user can press on an `Aircraft`, and navigate inside it, going to the `MainTabNavigator` where he can see the aircraft details with a bottom bar to navigate beetween them.

In this step I use the command

```js
navigation.navigate('MainTabNavigator')
```

This is my `MainTabNavigator`

```js
    <Tab.Navigator backBehavior='initialRoute'>
      <Tab.Screen name="SortiesNavigator" component={SortiesNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="DocumentationNavigator" component={DocumentationNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="PfrNavigator" component={PfrNavigator} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

Each one of the `Tab.Screen` are `StackNavigator`.

Everything is ok, except for a problem, I can't go back to the `AircraftList`, indeed if I press the device back button when I'm on the `SortiesNavigator`, I receive the development-only error

> "The action 'GO_BACK' was not handled by any navigator"

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: did you found the solution, I'm using helper function provided by reactnavigation v5 by setting up ref.
navigationRef.current.goBack(); to go back